# Why does my save use the initial value of my TextBox and not the entered value?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a textbox on my website:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Latitude" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:TextBox>
```

On page load I fill that textbox with something from a databse:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Latitude.Text = thisPlace.Latitude;
}
```

When I want to update my databse with a new value in that textbox, it still updated the database with the one put in on page load:

```
protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setCoordinates(Latitude.Text);
}
```

How can I make sure that `setCoordinates()` retrieves the new value from the textbox and not the initial value from the database from `Latitude.Text = thisPlace.Latitude;`?

Comment: Where do you call `setCoordinates`?

Comment: Where are you calling `setCoordinates()` from?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think its because [PostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you're calling `setCoordinates()` on some button's click event textbox's new value will be lost. If that's right change `Page_Load` like this one

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        Latitude.Text = thisPlace.Latitude;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This is because the `Page_Load` event happens before your method `setCoordinates` is called. This mean that the Latitude.Text value is the same as before.

You should change the load function so it does not always set the initial value of the textbox.

By changing the page_load event with `!Page.IsPostBack`, the only time the initial value is given, is the first time the page originaly loads.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
    {
        Latitude.Text = thisPlace.Latitude;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`Page_Load` executed each time page is loaded. Add `IsPostBack` check to reset text only on first page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Latitude.Text = thisPlace.Latitude;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check if the page is in postback otherwise the value will be replaced before the save

```
If(!IsPostBack){
    Latitude.Text = thisPlace.Latitude;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the information from the request rather than using the property like that:

```
var theValue = this.Context.Request[this.myTextBox.ClientID];
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you load initial values all over again.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    //call the function to load initial data into controls....
}
```