# If SQLDatasource returns 0 rows, change display:none to display:block

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I have a table with content that says

> 0 orders found

That is currently set in css

```
#OrderNoExist {
    display:none;
}
```

I'd like for the C# to change the css style for this table to block. Here's what I currently have, I'm wondering what's wrong with this? It steps through the entire method, but no change occurs? OrderNoExist is an ID.

```
    protected void SqlDataSource1_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AffectedRows < 1)
        {

            OrderNoExist.Attributes.CssStyle[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display] = "block";
            OrderNoExist.Style["display"] = "block";

        }
    }
```

**The markup:**

```
<table class="dxeTextBoxSys dxeTextBox_DevEx" id="OrderNoExist" style="color:Red;">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td class="dxic" style="width:100%;"><input class="dxeEditArea_DevEx dxeEditAreaSys" id="OrderNoExist_I" name="ctl00$ctl00$ASPxSplitter1$Content$ContentSplitter$MainContent$OrderNoExist" onfocus="aspxEGotFocus('OrderNoExist')" onblur="aspxELostFocus('OrderNoExist')" value="Order doesn't exist." type="text" style="color:Red;">
    </td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

The design before processing if it helps:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox runat="server" Theme="Metropolis" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="OrderNoExist" Text="Order doesn't exist." Width="107px" ForeColor="red"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

Comment: How does this "0 orders" label look in the markup?

Comment: It's just a text within a table. Plain "0 orders"

Comment: Sure, but the way it is implemented in the markup may be the reason why this does not work for you. Can you add it to the question?

Comment: Hi, I've just added the markup

Comment: Do you have more than one OrderNoExist control in your markup?

Comment: @bastos.sergio there's just one

Comment: Are you doing a partial postback?

Comment: @bastos.sergio I figured it out, answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the other controls were outside of the callbackpanel. The button was inside the callbackpanel so that's why the property changed for the button.

I just use one of the controls within the callbackpanel to display the error and it's working fine.

Comment: If you're using a callbackpanel, then you are doing a partial postback... ;)

Comment: Can you tell me the implications of this? This app I'm developing only shows the user information, no user entry is required.

Comment: The server sees a partial postback pretty much the same as a full/normal postback. The biggest difference lies with the browser. A partial postback is triggered by Ajax (so you need javascript) and it will only refresh the contents inside a callbackpanel--everything outside the callback panel will remain unchanged. You can use this to your advantage to keep javascript variables values for instance. (Outside the panel they will retain their value after a partial postback, but not after a full postback.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use *OrderNoExist.Style.Add("display", "block");*

Comment: @sojim2 may be it is better to make an outer *div* element and manipulate with him. Try to do this

Comment: I tried that, but the ID will be dynamic under devexpress controls.

Comment: <div id="myDiv" runat="server"><table class="dxeTextBoxSys dxeTextBox_DevEx" id="OrderNoExist" style="color:Red;">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td class="dxic" style="width:100%;"><input class="dxeEditArea_DevEx dxeEditAreaSys" id="OrderNoExist_I" name="ctl00$ctl00$ASPxSplitter1$Content$ContentSplitter$MainContent$OrderNoExist" onfocus="aspxEGotFocus('OrderNoExist')" onblur="aspxELostFocus('OrderNoExist')" value="Order doesn't exist." type="text" style="color:Red;">
    </td>
</tr></tbody></table></div>

Comment: And then in code behind: myDiv.Style.Add("display", "block");

Comment: So I found something interesting that's happened. When I apply the style on page_load, it works fine; however, when I put the code in `SqlDataSource1_Selected` although it steps through properly, the change doesn't appear on the page for some reason. Also, I've tried the myDiv runat method and it expands the ID to something quite large:  `ctl00_ctl00_ASPxSplitter1_Content_ContentSplitter_MainContent_myDiv`

Comment: I think it has to do something with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261850/asp-net-text-of-textbox-does-not-change-in-code-behind