# Insert value into textbox when a checkbox is ticked

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a form that adds suppliers using SQL

There is `SupplierID` , `SupplierName` , `SupplierProduceType` , `SupplierPhone` going into the `Supplier` table

[image: Form page]

I have no trouble with the ID,name and phone however produce type is difficult as there is 1-5 options which can be selected

i want the textbox to display `beef,pork,chicken,lamb,sauce` (separated by commas) if there 5 are checked, obviously if only 3 are selected i want only those 3 to show

when i hit the add supplier button, the sql code will be:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO[Supplier](SupplierID, SupplierName, SupplierProduceType, SupplierPhone) Values('" + Convert.ToInt32(SupplierIDTB.Text) + "', '" + SupplierNameTB.Text + "', '" + SupplierProduceTypeTB.Text + "', '" + Convert.ToInt32(SupplierPhoneTB.Text) + "')";
```

So when the sql code reads from the SupplierProduceTypeTB.Text it will read "beef,pork,chicken,lamb,sauce" (if all 5 are checked) and input that into the SupplierProduceType column

So far i have:

```
protected void BeefCB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String input1 = "beef,";
        SupplierProduceTypeTB.Text += input1;
    }
```

but this does nothing!

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261850/text-of-textbox-does-not-change-in-code-behind    Asp.Net is a little weird about updating values in the code-behind portions of things.

Comment: thats a bad design to me. What if you want to find all suppliers that sells pork? you can't effectively index that column if you used string concat. And please, do not use sql injectable string.

Comment: i wont be wanting to search suppliers that sell pork, thats outside the scope of this project, just want to list what each supplier sells

Comment: Before you write another of code you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. Your code is wide open to sql injection and my friend [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) loves this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You just only need to change a little bit in your code.

try below code

```
     protected void BeefCB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
           SupplierProduceType();
     }
     protected void PorkCB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
           SupplierProduceType();
     }
     protected void ChickenCB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
           SupplierProduceType();
     }
     protected void LambCB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
           SupplierProduceType();
     }
     protected void SauceCB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
           SupplierProduceType();
     }

     private void SupplierProduceType()
     {
           string produceType = string.Empty;
           if(BeefCB.Checked)
           {
               produceType = "Beef, ";
           }
           if(PorkCB_Checked)
           {
               produceType += "Pork, ";
           }
           if(ChickenCB_Checked)
           {
               produceType += "Chicken, ";
           }
           if(LambCB_Checked)
           {
               produceType += "Lamb, ";
           }
           if(SauceCB_Checked)
           {
               produceType += "Sauce, ";
           }
           SupplierProduceTypeTB.Text = produceType;
    }
```

As += will not work on textbox.Text property.

Try this one by creating function and call it to you every checkbox checkchange method.

Comment: IT works. BUT. if i de-select beef it adds another "beef," to the textbox (doesnt remove it)... i will try an if statement

Comment: SO my way around was to do an if statement in the add supplier button

Comment: So in that case you need to write if and else statement like if(BeefCB.Checked){//write code to add beef } else{//Write code to remove beef}

Comment: I have updated the answer with improvement in code. You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

SO my way around was to do an if statement in the add supplier button:

```
if (BeefCB.Checked) {
            String input1 = "beef,";
            string textboxValue = SupplierProduceTypeTB.Text;
            SupplierProduceTypeTB.Text = textboxValue + input1;
        }

        if (PorkCB.Checked) {
            String input1 = "pork,";
            string textboxValue = SupplierProduceTypeTB.Text;
            SupplierProduceTypeTB.Text = textboxValue + input1;
        }

        if (ChickenCB.Checked) {
            String input1 = "chicken,";
            string textboxValue = SupplierProduceTypeTB.Text;
            SupplierProduceTypeTB.Text = textboxValue + input1;
        }

        if (LambCB.Checked) {
            String input1 = "lamb,";
            string textboxValue = SupplierProduceTypeTB.Text;
            SupplierProduceTypeTB.Text = textboxValue + input1;
        }

        if (SauceCB.Checked) {
            String input1 = "sauce";
            string textboxValue = SupplierProduceTypeTB.Text;
            SupplierProduceTypeTB.Text = textboxValue + input1;
        }
```